# Can anyone identify why my loop isn't working correctly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do an insert, so that when a clientID value is NULL then insert the client data into the client table.

I have a loop that cycles through data entered into a temp table,  when the clientID is null it should do an insert and choose the next sequential client reference for that client then delete the row from the temp table and move onto the next.

The problem is when the loop does the second insert or more, it is using the SAME client reference even though I have specified +1. The below is an extract of the loop, can anyone figure out why after the first insert the client reference stays the same? If I run the insert by itself with the loop and select @result it shows the vaues sequentially so I don't understand why when the script runs it doesn't insert the reference sequentially.

```
  Declare @Id int
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)
begin
select top 1 @id = ID from #temp

IF (select clientID from #m1 where id = @id) is null AND  (select renewalinsuredid from #m1 where id=@id) is not null and (select renewalmasterID from #m1 where id=@id) is not null 
BEGIN
declare @result varchar(10)
SELECT @Result = (MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ClientReference1,3,6) AS INTEGER)) + 1) FROM Client
set @result = 'CR0' + @result

INSERT INTO Client (clientid,InsuredName,InsuredId,MasterInsuredId,ClientReference1)
SELECT newid(),insuredname,RenewalInsuredID,RenewalMasterID,@result from #M1 where id = @id

PRINT 'Client ref '+ cast(@result as varchar(64))  +' inserted for policy ' + @result2
END



DELETE from #temp where ID = @Id
END
```

Comment: That code is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Re-tagges with `sql-server` based on the syntax used.

Comment: Are there really two separate temp tables here (`#m1` and `#temp`) or is this incomplete anonymization of some kind? If there are two tables, how are they related? Some sample table from both may be informative.

Comment: There are two temporary tables with the same data. One is used in the loop where the rows are deleted and the other is used for before/after results queries.

Comment: What is your input and and expected output? For sure you can do this requirement without looping... Why you require looping in sql server?

Comment: Please do not write "LOOPS" like this in Sql Server.  This is not set-based code.  This is RBAR (row by agonizing row) code.

Comment: The input is the @result for the client reference.
granadaCoder , this is literally the definition of a loop in code, please refer to google.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly a loop. No, nobody is questioning that this is a loop. No, writing loops in T-SQL is not a good idea. This can be rewritten as one `INSERT Client ... SELECT ... FROM #temp WHERE ...`, using a `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the references.

Comment: select top 1 @id = ID from #temp  --this should have an ORDER BY otherwise top 1 could be any row

Answer (score 0):

you do...

```
SELECT @Result = (MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ClientReference1,3,6) AS INTEGER)) + 1) FROM Client
```

...to get the maximum client reference CAST to an integer, then add 1 to it - this doesn't guarantee that @Result is 'greater' than all the other ClientReference1, because ClientReference1 appears to be a text field - consider a field '9', cast it to integer, and add 1 - what have you got? A 10 - if I change back to text, then '10' < '9' in terms of alphanumerics

interchanging from numeric to string, and sorting numerics that have changed to strings, can have unwanted effects.  Also you add'CR0' to the start of the string, that could confuse things possibly.

Comment: You pretty much got it right, it seems to be to do with the data type. I'll show what I did to resolve it in an answer below - Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it to work after converting the value. It seems to be due to the datatype being int as when converted to varchar the insert works correctly. The main thing that I don't understand is how if i just did select @result to see what the output was - it was correct every time, just didn't seem to insert the value correctly. Thanks for the help people.

```
 declare @result varchar(10)
     declare   @Length         int
     declare    @Refresult      varchar(10)

SELECT @Result = (MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ClientReference1,3,6) AS INTEGER)) + 1) FROM Client
   SET    @Length =  CONVERT(INT,@Result)
   SET    @Result =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Length)
   SET    @Length =  LEN(@Result)
 IF(@Length =5)
      SET @Result = '0' + @Result
    IF @Result IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = '00000' + '1'
    END
SET @Refresult = 'CR' + @Result
```